# How join similar value and sum (related tables) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

There are two tables: **post**, **foreword**
There are two columns in post table: **id**, **foreword_id**

I want to select all POST IDs and count the sum of the same FOREWORD ID  for this POST ID.

```
public function foreword()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Foreword');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before anyone can give you a working solution, you'll need to specify what you've already tried and provide the code you're trying to fix.

Comment: How do you want to count `foreword_id` for `post`, when your `post` belongs to only one `foreword`?

Comment: @Tarasovych, yes

Comment: So, how?) You have one-to-many relation between posts and forewords. One post can have only one foreword at a time. So the `SUM()` of `foreword_id` would be `foreword_id` value itself.

Comment: @Tarasovych, oops ;)  One post can have only one foreword at a time :)